# What am I doing wrong on set UIImage as circular?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, constraints

How do I keep the UIImageView circular and centralized on each cell without losing the circular format like below?

```
        self.gameImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.gameImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.gameImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.gameImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.gameImage.frame.height / 2.0
        self.gameImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

***Constraints:***
[image]

***App Running:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraints are not limiting the image view to be a square, therefore, when you round the corners, you get an oval and not a circle. To get a circle, you need to rethink your constraints so that the image view is always a square:

- Remove the trailing space constraint
- Remove the leading space constraint
- Add an Aspect Ratio constraint on the image view with a 1:1 ratio
- Add an explicit height or width constraint on the image view
- Add an Align Center X to Superview constraint on the image view

These constraints will keep the image view centered in the parent view and keep the image view as a square so when you round the corners, it appears as a circle. It will disassociate the image view from the container's leading and trailing edges so if the view can appear at many different sizes, you may need to rethink how you set the view's explicit height or width.

Comment: Hello dude! I followed your explanation and worked very well! However, I got an error on the UIIMageView position. Could you try to help me out, please? I just updated the post

Comment: This correct-seeming answer didn't mention a y-axis constraint.  Add one of those, too.  (Either center Y, or top space)

Comment: @danh The post was edited. The original image had a top constraint which was removed.

Comment: @TituJow Readd the top constraint that was in the first screenshot. Not sure why you deleted that one and then added a second bottom constraint.